# DateTimeOffset ParseExact - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

i am trying to parse this date `14.03.2014 22:16:23` using `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` but i get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

What i already tried:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("14.03.2014 22:16:23", "G", new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your custom format pattern like;

```
var date = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("14.03.2014 22:16:23",
                                     "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                      new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Output will be;

```
3/14/2014 10:16:23 PM +00:00
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/a99iDe)</kbd>.

From it's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343428%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> A format specifier that defines the **expected format of input**.

Your [`G` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) does not work on this case because it is a [*standar date and time format*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you really want to use it, you can do;

For example;

```
var off  = DateTimeOffset.Parse("14.03.2014 22:16:23");
Console.WriteLine(off.ToString("G"));
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i determine it myself, as i don't want to repeat that kind of questions again. And learn new things ofc.

Comment: @RuneS What do you mean by _determine it myself_ ? I suggest to start read their documentations.